# Firebase Security Measures

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have this in Firebase:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2qdqmb33krbwv2s/Screenshot%202015-09-14%2015.42.45.png?dl=0

Right now when you put script tags in reminder, the script will perform. I want every time when someone adds data and if in that data contains <> symbols, .write to be false.

Can anyone assist me how can i do this? I can't find the right information in documentation for Security.

Thank you.

**Updated (Solution):**

```
{
"rules": {
  "reminders": {
    ".read": true,
    "$-":{
    ".write": true,
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['reminder', 'status'])",
    "reminder" :{
     ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ?!]+$/)"
    },
    "status" :{
      ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^[0-9]*$/)"  
    }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Please include the JSON itself, instead of a link to a picture of it. A snippet like `new Firebase('https://mine.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) { console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val(), null, '\t')); }, function(e) { console.error(e); })` is all it takes. Also: what rules did you try?

Comment: I get this error: Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.(…)
I've tried everything from the documentation... i can't set it up the way i want.

Comment: The answer will use this function: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/string/contains.html But unless you show the actual JSON and the rules you tried, I cannot do a lot for you.

Comment: I did it. This is how:{
    "rules": {
      "reminders": {
        "$-":{
          ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['reminder', 'status'])",
        "reminder" :{
         ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)"
        },
        "status" :{
          ".validate": "newData.val().matches(/^[0-9]*$/)"  
        }
        }
      }
    }
}

Thanks anyway. :)